# ListView or SingleChildScrollView of variable size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to have a widget of variable height that contains a `ListView` or a `SingleChildScrollView` or anything that scrolls.

I tried making it like this:

```
Container(
    color: Colors.pink,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(color: Colors.orange, child: Text("Header")),
        SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                height: 10000,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text("the height of this content could be anything")),
          ),

        Container(color: Colors.blue, child: Text("Footer")),
      ],
    ),
)
```

This causes an overflow because the `SingleChildScrollView` expands to height of 10000 pixels. If I enclose it in an `Expanded` then it works fine but then if its child's height is for example 200 instead of 10000, it will still expand the parent widget to the entire height of the screen.

Is it possible to have the height of the scroll/list adjust itself to its content and only expand to the entire screen if it needs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it if you know the size of the `footer` and `header` widget and using `LayoutBuilder` widget to get the constraints.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext newcontext) {
    return Center(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            color: Colors.pink,
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (_, constraints) {

                final sizeHeader = 150.0;
                final sizeFooter = 150.0;
                final sizeList = 1000.0;
                final available =
                    constraints.maxHeight - (sizeHeader + sizeFooter);

                Widget _buildCenterWidget() {
                  return Container(
                    height: sizeList,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text("the height of this content could be anything"),
                  );
                }

                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        height: sizeHeader,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        child: Text("Header")),
                    available < sizeList
                        ? Expanded(
                            child: _buildCenterWidget(),
                          )
                        : _buildCenterWidget(),
                    Container(
                        height: sizeFooter,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text("Footer")),
                  ],
                );
              },
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the height for header or footer, but I'll make it work somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConstrainedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html), to specify minHeight, maxHeight for your widget. Remember that none of your widget should have infinite height/width, that spoils the UI, may also throw error